# How to make an edit box disapper at runtime (NOT gray) in MSVC 2008 using MFC?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-interface, mfc

I want to make an EditBox disappear completely when the user selects a particular iption, instead of just graying it out. I tried using EnableWindow(false), but that just grays it out. I want the user to not see the control at all...can anyone help, or is this not possible in MSVC 2008 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ShowWindow?:

```
shan23EditBox.ShowWindow(FALSE);
```

Comment: technically, `shan32EditBox.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);`

Answer (score 2):

Try something m_EditBoxCtrl.ShowWindow(FALSE);

And by the way, google answers more faster on such kind of questions. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Blv me, i tried googling, but apparently my search strings were not good enough :) . Btw, StackOverflow is faster than google as I'm finding now , thanks to u guys !!